# Access denied for mysql user

Tags: php, mysql

sir, i have uploaded my website to hosting
and when i run it, eror, how can i fix this
i try before without those code that show how many member,topic,and comment i have in database
and it works, but when i put the code to show that, it bcome like access denied

```
<font face="comic sans MS">
<img src="image/header.jpg"  width="100%">
    <table border="1" widht="100%" height="50" align="center" bgcolor="#FBFBEF">
    <tr>    
        <td width="90%"  align="left" valign="bottom" ><img src="image/start.gif" alt="icon" width="26" height="26"></td>
        <th><b>Welcome, Guest,please  <a href="login.php" style="text-decoration:none; color:green">Login</a>" or "<a href="register.php" style="text-decoration:none; color:red">Register</a></b></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="50%" align="left" valign="bottom"><font size="5" id="welcome"><strong>Welcome To Squad 3.0 Ghz FORUM</strong></font> </td>
        <td id=clock align="right" valign="center"><strong><iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i4eh41xm/n108/tlsg/fn7/fs12/tct/pct/ftb/tt0/tw1/tm1/th1" frameborder="0" width="182" height="20" allowTransparency="true"></iframe><strong></td>
    </tr>
<table border="1" bgcolor="#FBFBEF" width="100%">
    <tr>

        <td align="left" width="70%"><b><a href="index.php" ><img src="image/homeicon.png" widht="20" height="20"></td>

        <td align="right" width="7%">
        <?php
        include 'connection.php';
        $query1="select count(email) as num_user from user_login";
        $result1=mysql_query($query1);
        $row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1);
        echo '*'.$row1['num_user'].'* Member';
        ?>
        </td>&nbsp <td align="right" width="5%">
        <?php
        include 'connection.php';
        $query2="select count(topic_id) as num_topic from topic";
        $result2=mysql_query($query2);
        $row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2);
        echo '*'.$row2['num_topic'].'* Topic';
        ?>


        </td>&nbsp <td align="right" width="7%">
        <?php
        include 'connection.php';
        $query3="select count(topic_id) as num_comment from comment";
        $result3=mysql_query($query3);
        $row3=mysql_fetch_array($result3);
        echo '*'.$row3['num_comment'].'* Comment';
        ?>

        </td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

this is my code,
and the result is here
http://uasforum22.zz.mu.zz.mu/

Comment: Just check with manual connection in your file i.e. add the connection string in your file rather then including external file

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please do that, and explain where/when it fails.

Answer (score 1):

The error suggests that the username and password you are using to connect to the mysql database is incorrect - "Access denied for user". You hosting provider in all probability must have provided a utility(cpanel) to create/delete user (and password).
Please create a new user and assign a password to same and use this credential in your connection.php. Also remember to grant all priviledges to this user temporarily. Later on once you are done with testing the db connection issues you may want to reduce access priviledge.